# Control the rotation of an environment map

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I use the following node setup for world settings:

[image: node setup - world]

Notice the keyframe on the z-axis in the mapping node. At the end of the animation, the environment map will be rotated by a full 360 degrees.

The rotation defaults to a bezier curve, which I don't want - I want to switch it to a linear rotation, to be able to create a continuous loop. However, this animation never shows up in the graph editor.

(I understand that the graph editor shows only curves on the selected objects, but how do you 'select' the environment map? You can't even click the 'world' entry in the outliner.)

Is there any other way to control the animations behaviour?

I am using Blender v2.75.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]Select the mapping node in the compositor, then go to your animation scene, to your graph editor and you can change it to linear.